# Return true called inside LINQ Select statement

Tags: c#, linq

I ran across some code in an older project I am working on that I've never seen before, and has me confused on it's intent.

```
updatables.Select(r =>
{
  // some operations are done here for each element in the list  
  return true;
}).ToArray();
```

It seems like a select statement is being used to iterate the updatables collection. Also seems the `ToArray` call isn't doing anything.

My question is, what does calling return true in the `Select` statement accomplish, if anything?

Comment: For every entity from original collection returns `true`. Basically projecting original entity to `boolean`. The result is `IEnumerable<bool>`. ToArray execute the LINQ query... But problem is that `some operation` which is executed will do side effect but `Select` is not meant to do that...

Comment: It looks like a quick and ugly LINQ version of `foreach`.

Comment: It's an update?

Comment: Why people think that LINQ is faster than a foreach loop? The opposite is true here, a new array with the same size as `updatables` is created  for no obvious reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks very much like a hack to emulate `ForEach`:

- `ToArray()` call is added to ensure that `updatables` will be iterated to completion,
- `return true` is added to silence the compiler that does not allow `Action<T>`, but allows `Func<T,bool>` in LINQ's `Select`.

I would strongly recommend against writing code like this, because it is a lot less readable than an equivalent `foreach` loop.

Comment: Or use something that's purpose built for such a task, such as [morelinq's ForEach](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ#foreach).

Answer (score 3):

`Select` takes a `Func<T, TResult>` - which means it won't accept an `Action<T>`. In other words, a lambda which does not return anything will result in a compilation error when passed to `Select`, so the author bypassed that "limitation" by having it return a dummy value.

The intent behind this code is likely to run a `foreach` loop on the collection using the LINQ syntax. However, the way it's done in this code is a bad practice, as LINQ methods are expected to be pure - that is, not modify any sort of state outside of the expression.